# What is the life time of a C++ data structure object?

Tags: c++, data-structures, object-lifetime

Suppose I have have a `Car.h` which define a class called Car , and I have implementation Car.cpp which implement my `class Car`, for example my `Car.cpp` can be :

```
struct Helper { ... };
Helper helpers[] = { /* init code */  };
Car::Car() {}
char *Car::GetName() { .....}
```

What is the life time of the helpers array ?
Do I need say `static Helper helpers[];` ?
If I have done some bad practices, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variable declared/defined in global / namespace scope has a complete life time until the code ends.

If you want your `Helper helpers[];` to be accessible only within `Car.cpp` then only you should declare it as `static`; otherwise let it be a global. In other words,

```
Helper helpers[];        // accessible everywhere if `extern`ed to the file
static Helper helpers[];  // accessible only in `Car.cpp`
```

**Edit**: As, @andrewdski suggested in comment below; you should make `helpers[]` as `static` variable since you are using it within this file; even though `Helper` is not visible outside. In C++, if 2 entirely different unit has same named global variables then compiler **silently** create a mess by referring them to the same memory location.

Comment: I posted an answer that misunderstood the question, but this is correct.  I thought the code he posted was the header file!  In any case, I would say best practice would be to use `static` to make `helpers` local to the .CPP file (assuming, as seems likely, that is the intent).

Comment: @andrewdski, yes you  are right. However, since the `Helper` is declared within `.cpp` file, it will not have any effect whether `helper[]` is made `static` or not.

Comment: It will pollute the global namespace.  Suppose he later writes a Truck.cpp that also needs a `helper` array.

Comment: @iammilind, to clarify andrewdski, the name becames a globally visible name `helper`. Should another file declare a distinct object called `helper` you'll get a linker error about duplicate symbols. Alternately another file could use `extern` and gain access to the original `helper` variable. To prevent this one must use either `static` or an anonymous namespace.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y, ya I got his point at that time. I have edited my answer. Thanks @andrewdski, I missed that point of similar name problem

Comment: Okay, but it won't *silently* create a mess. The linker will refuse to link -- otherwise you have a severely broken linker.

Comment: if I have a helper function that should be local to the file , should I also declare it static as well ?  How about struct Helper ; can it name-collide with another other types outside of this file ?

Comment: @dan_L, `struct Helper` would not collide; but to point that it's just used in the given file, you can put it inside **unnamed** namespace. i.e. `namespace { struct Helper {... }; }`; apart from this whatever function/objects are local to the file, **always** declare them `static`.

Answer (score 2):

Objects defined at file scope are called `Static Storage Duration` objects.

In most situations you can think of them as being created before main() is entered and destroyed after main() is exited (there are exceptions but I would not worry about that).

- The order of destruction of static storage duration variables is the reverse order of creation.
- The order of creation within the same compilation unit (file) is the order they are declared.

  - Note: There is no guarantee about the order of creation of `Static Storage Duration` objects across different compilation units.